# How do I make my selenium tests detectable by the server?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm currently working on making a few improvements to our selenium based UI tests. One feature I'm looking for is a reliable way for our website to detect what traffic is coming from our tests, so I can filter this traffic out of our browser usage metrics and logging.

One thought I had is to set a tracking cookie with selenium that I could read server side to append to my logs/metrics making it easier to filter it out. The challenge here is cookies are domain specific, and as far as I know wouldn't be readable from other sites. Cookies are also a finite resource, and given the size/distributed nature of our website it's quite possible to run into a situation where this could blow the size limit on cookies/headers and cause issues in the page.

Is this my best option, or is there another reliable way to detect from my webserver if my page is being automated with selenium. (I'm not trying to combat bots, we have other systems in place to guard against DoS/DDoS attacks.

Comment: Seems like user-agent would be easiest

Answer (score 0):

When using Chrome, the Selenium driver injects a webdriver property into the browser’s navigator object. This means that for me, adding the following js to my page redirected it to StackOverflow:

```
if (navigator.webdriver == true) {
    window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

So I guess just replace `window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com";` with whatever you want, I'm guessing logging the requests somewhere or somehow excluding them from whatever tool you use to measure traffic.

Answer (score 0):

So, the server obviously needs some token that tells it that a session is selenium based. Given that, here is what I would do.

Create a super simple API on your server. Have that API take the session token of the logged in used and pass that in the API (almost always automatic). When the API receives that session token, mark something in the database (new table or same table that stores session ID's if any).

Have the API flag the session as a test session, and thus not valid for metrics.

This is not a statistically significant impact on any server, so there is no worry about resources or impact.

Should take a very simple code-behind API, a very lightweight table that could simply have a single column with a foreign key to the session id involved. All inserted session IDs in this table, by virtue of existing here, are test sessions.

And then, your metrics recording will need to add a single clause to a query that has effectively "WHERE (SELECT COUNT(sessionId) FROM TestSessionsTable WHERE sessionId = currentIdChecked) = 0"

And that would give you what you need. I am happy to be told of a better solution, but this strikes me as the simplest effort, with the least impact on resources.

As for detecting Webdriver sessions on the client side, you can either use C. Peck's suggestion, or directly call the API from your automation run using the WebDriver's Javascript Executor logic.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered whether OP wanted to track selenium traffic on the server as well as the client side.